# When were OLEDB based linked servers added to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I guess what I'm asking is in which version of SQL Server were linked servers added to SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was introduced in SQL 7. If memory serves me right, I was able to access a SQL 6.5 server from a SQL 7 server, but I could not access SQL 6.5 from/to another SQL 6.5 (I don't think the sp_addlinkedserver stored procedure existed prior to SQL 7).

Comment: I've got a help file for SQL Server 6.0 and can confirm that certainly there is no mention of `sp_addlinkedserver` in that. That has `sp_addserver` for remote servers. I'm not sure what the difference is in remote vs linked servers.

Comment: sp_addserver is not for remote servers. It's for local servers and used when you change the computer name where your SQL Server instance is hosted. Not many users do such things anymore but if you ever do, first sp_dropserver 'original_server_name' then sp_addserver 'current_server_name', 'local'

Comment: @SQLmojoe - this is what the SQL Server 6.0 help file says http://i.stack.imgur.com/GCZvk.png. I have highlighted the word "or".